# ListBox list identical after second run of Sub with different InputBox variable value

Tags: excel, vba, global-variables, inputbox

So I have a spreadsheet with a bunch of sheets that list names in the first column. On one sheet, the `Input` sheet, I have a command button that opens a `Sub` that prompts the user to perform a search of the names columns on each sheet by requesting a string via `searchStr = InputBox(“Please enter text to search for:”,”Search for name”)`, where `searchStr` is declared as a global variable with `Public searchStr As String`.

Upon submission of this input, all names in all sheets are sifted through for string matches and returned to a `ListBox` in a `UserForm`. The user then makes a selection from the names that populate the `ListBox` and is redirected to the sheet which contains their selection.

This all works great – until the user runs the sub the second time. The `InuptBox`, once again, prompts the user for input and the user obliges and submits only to be met with the exact same `ListBox` list of names even though their input was vastly different and the potential matches also wildly dissimilar… and so the user hits the `Cancel` button.

And then on the third run, it corrects itself and the `ListBox` populates as it should, which is to say correctly.

What’s going on, and how can I fix it?

Here's the code that passes the search string to the `UserForm`:

```
Sub searchRostSheets()
    
    searchStr = InputBox("Please enter the text you wish to search for:", "Search")
    
'   Check for existence of roster data

    Dim rosterSh As Worksheet
    Dim numStudents As Integer, totalStudents As Integer
    totalStudents = 0
    
    For Each rosterSh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Set rosterSh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(rosterSh.Name)
        
        If rosterSh.Name Like "*Roster*" Then
            numStudents = rosterSh.Range("A" & rosterSh.Range("A:A").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        
            If numStudents = 1 Then
                ' MsgBox "You have not entered any roster data for " & rosterSh.Name & ".", vbExclamation, "Alert"
                GoTo nextSheet
            Else
                ' Proceed
            End If
            
            numStudents = numStudents - 1
        End If
        
        totalStudents = totalStudents + numStudents
        
nextSheet:
    Next rosterSh
    
    If totalStudents = 0 Then
        MsgBox "You have not entered any roster data." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "You must enter roster data to perform this task.", vbExclamation, "Alert"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        ' Proceed
    End If

    UserForm9.Show
    
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

And here is the code that pertains to the `UserForm` with the `ListBox`:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With
    
    Dim sheet As Worksheet, rosterSh As Worksheet
    Dim numStudents As Integer, searchCell As Range, i As Integer, listboxValCheck As Boolean
    Dim firstSearchAddr As String, lastSearchAddr As String
    Dim searchDict As Object
    Set searchDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        
    For Each sheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    
        If sheet.Name Like "*Roster*" Then
            Set rosterSh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheet.Name)
             
            firstSearchAddr = "A2" 'in cell A2
            lastSearchAddr = "C" & rosterSh.Columns("C").Find("*", , xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).row
            
            
                
                For Each searchCell In rosterSh.Range(firstSearchAddr & ":" & lastSearchAddr)
                    Dim listboxStr As String
                    If InStr(searchCell.Value, searchStr) > 0 Or InStr(UCase(searchCell.Value), UCase(searchStr)) > 0 Or InStr(LCase(searchCell.Value), LCase(searchStr)) > 0 Then
                        Select Case searchCell.Column
                            Case 1
                                listboxStr = searchCell.Value & "   [" & Replace(rosterSh.Name, " Roster", "") & "]" & "                                   " & searchCell.Address
                            Case 2
                                listboxStr = searchCell.Offset(0, -1).Value & "   [" & Replace(rosterSh.Name, " Roster", "") & "]" & "                                   " & searchCell.Offset(0,-1).Address
                            Case 3
                                listboxStr = searchCell.Offset(0, -2).Value & "   [" & Replace(rosterSh.Name, " Roster", "") & "]" & "                                   " & searchCell.Offset(0,-2).Address
                        End Select
                        
                        If searchDict.Exists(listboxStr) Then
                            ' listboxStr is already in dictionary
                        Else
                            searchDict.Add listboxStr, searchDict.Count
                            selectionListBox.AddItem listboxStr
                        End If
EndfOfLoop:
                    End If
                    
                Next searchCell
                       
        End If
        
    Next sheet
        
    searchDict.RemoveAll
        
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub OK_Click()

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

'   Set sheet to current sheet
    Dim rosterSh As Worksheet, rosterShName As String
    Dim selectedStu As String, stuAddr As String
    
    If selectionListBox.ListIndex < 0 Then
        MsgBox "You did not make a selection. Please make a selection or press " & Chr(34) & "Cancel" & Chr(34) & " to continue.", vbExclamation, "Alert"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        selectedStu = selectionListBox.List(selectionListBox.ListIndex)
        rosterShName = Trim(Split(Replace(Split(selectedStu, "[")(1), "]", ""), "$")(0)) & " Roster"
        stuAddr = Split(Trim(Split(selectedStu, "]")(1)), "$")(2)
    End If
    
    Set rosterSh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(rosterShName)
    rosterSh.Activate
    rosterSh.Rows(stuAddr & ":" & stuAddr).Select

    Call unloadUserForm9
    UserForm9.Hide
    
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
    
Exit Sub

End Sub

Private Sub Cancel_Click()
    If Not UserForm9 Is Nothing Then
        Call unloadUserForm9
        UserForm9.Hide
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    UserForm9.Hide
    Call unloadUserForm9
    If CloseMode = 0 Then
        ' DO NOTHING
    End If
End Sub
```

I also have a `Public searchStr As String` declaration in `Module 1`.

EDIT 2: I’ve tried adding a `selectionListBox.Clear` in the unloading function, but that didn’t work.

Comment: You haven't shown any relevant code so what could we suggest?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand why. Every other piece of code works as you would expect it to work, so I don’t see how the error could have occurred anywhere else.

Comment: You posted a single line of code, which seems fine, so likely the issue is somewhere else.  "works as you would expect it to work" doesn't seem to be the case, based on what you describe.

Comment: Sounds to me like you are using (and then re-using) the UserForms default insurance and so seeing the same data (when the UserForm is re-shown). As @TimWilliams says, though, it is not possible to confirm without seeing the code

Comment: My apologies, I was having a moment last night and got caught up in my own hubris - admittedly, unjustifiably. I have attached my code so that you can help.

Comment: What happens in `unloadUserForm9` ?

Comment: Just `Unload UserForm9`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
Unload UserForm9
```

to correctly destroy the instance of the user form object on your click events. Only if you use Unload (not .Hide) to close the userform the initialize event will trigger when showing the userform again which will fill the listbox correctly.

After you used Unload (in a macro or not) you have to remove all UserForm related code in your macros such as UserForm9.Hide after that unloading call. This would otherwise always trigger the initialize event again with the old value of your global variable. If you unload your userform, make sure, you do it at the end of all doings in the userform unless you want to initialize it again.

And please do not make use of jump points in your code. Especially your loops are terribly designed with this jump marks.

Comment: I've neglected to include the code that does that, but I do in fact unload `UserForm` with the `unloadUserForm9`  function that's called in my `OK_Click()` routine.

Comment: Well, could you check then in debugger, if the initialize evet is called when running the sub the 2nd time? thanks

Comment: I checked. It is initializing.

Comment: At the second run of initializing, the listbox items list is empty in debugger? Thats the only thing i could imagine now. Except you enter the same search strings.

Comment: `selectionListBox.ListCount` is 0. And I have entered different strings. I’m not near my device at the moment so I can’t test this, but would it help to create a function in the same module as the `searchRostSheets()` routine and call that one with `UserForm_Initialize`?

Comment: Ah well, no. You did a terrible mistake. I saw it now. After you call your Unload Macro, where you unload your userform, you call Userform9.Hide
This is calling the initializing event again with the value of searchStr from first call. After you call the sub again, initializing isn't called again (so wrong again in your post). Please remove all UserForm9.Hide calls and it should work.
I edited my answer above, please mark as correct if it works.

Comment: Moving the `UserForm9.Hide` before the `Unload` call worked. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to hide it, because unloading will cause to disappear of the userform at all :)

Comment: Also, when in the userform code module, use `Me` to refer to *that specific instance* of the userform.  If you had called `Unload Me` and then `Me.Hide` you would have seen a run-time error (because you can't hide a userform you just unloaded) rather than your auto-instancing second UserForm9